# Wix util:registrysearch unrecognized

Tags: wix, sharpdevelop

I am using Sharp Develop 4.4.1 to create a wix installer package for my application. The WIX version is the one that came with Sharp Develop, namely version 3.8.
My MSI project builds just fine.
Now I want to include the MSI in a bundle. In the bundle, I want to check if .net 4.5 and ghostscript are installed (otherwise install it). The .net package check is a breeze using packagegroupref.
So far so good.

However, I also want to check if Ghostscript is installed and intend to do this by doing a registry search. Since I am working in a Bundle, I am trying to use `<util:RegistrySearch.....`, but I get an error stating: `The Fragment element contains an unhandled extension element 'util:RegistrySearch'.  Please ensure that the extension for elements in the 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension' namespace has been provided. (CNDL0200) - d:\SharpDev Projects\NREOutlookTest1\AIFBundle\Setup.wxs:20`

This is my bundle code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Bundle UpgradeCode="ae0120aa-0ba8-45ac-b3e5-fce0f6b05de6"
    Name="!(bind.packageName.AIF)" 
          Version="!(bind.packageVersion.AIF)" 
          Manufacturer="!(bind.packageManufacturer.AIF)"
    IconSourceFile=".\images\stamp.ico">
   <WixVariable Id="WixStdbaLicenseUrl" Value="myurl" />
   <WixVariable Id="WixStdbaLogoFile" Value="..\NREOutlookTest1\images\stamp.jpg" />
   <WixVariable Id="WixStdbaLogoSideFile" Value="..\NREOutlookTest1\images\stamp.jpg" />
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkSidebarLicense" />
    <Chain>
     <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx45Web" />
     <PackageGroupRef Id="Ghostscript" />
    <MsiPackage Id="AIF" SourceFile="..\AIFSetup\bin\Release\AIFSetup.msi" Visible="no" />
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
 <Fragment>
  <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\GPL Ghostscript\9.14" Value="GS_DLL" Variable="GhostScriptDetect" />
  <PackageGroup Id="Ghostscript">
      <ExePackage
       Id="gs914"
       DisplayName="GPL Ghostscript"
              Cache="no"
              Compressed="no"
              Permanent="no"
              Vital="yes"
       DetectCondition="GhostScriptDetect &gt;&gt; &quot;gsdll32.dll&quot;"
              InstallCommand="/S"
     SourceFile="gs914w32.exe"      
              DownloadUrl="http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/gs914w32.exe" />
      </PackageGroup>
 </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I have included the Wix Extension WixUtilExtension.dll in the project:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I noticed just now, the executable does get created and guess what. It works! During build I get an error, but still it produces a solid executable. How about that!

Comment: SharpDevelop no longer installs WiX itself. Trying WiX 3.7 I can only reproduce the error message if the WixUtilExtension.dll is not referenced by the project. Also when I do a full Rebuild nothing is generated by WiX for me if the WixUtilExtension.dll is not referenced.

Comment: You are right, I installed the wix 3.8 toolkit myself. My setup.exe is build by sharpdevelop, despite the error message, but the registry key is not queried by the setup.exe. I ran procmon to monitor the registry actions and could not find the query in the log.

I did add the extensions to the WiX Extensions in the project and I even tried adding them as References. The same error message appears. What is it I am doing wrong??

If I start typing util:reg... i do get code completion suggestions

Comment: Are you maybe confusing 32-bit/64-bit? That search is the 32-bit registry and maybe you're on a 64-bit system and used procmon on the native 64-bit directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I am officially an idiot. I have a post compile script running in sharpdevelop that is doing a candle and light action. I forgot to include the extension in the candle command, which gave me the error. DOH!!